# Custom css for Amcharts

Tags: angular, amcharts

I'm using Amcharts 4 and Angular 7. Could not find any resources to use a custom css for the tooltip. Explored amchart site and the questions here in Stackoverflow but no similar question. Anyone who knows about this? Would appreciate any help. I could use  inlign styling but code would be cleaner with external css.

Comment: Hello gladsching, looks like it is your first post on StackOverflow. I recommend providing more insight about which Angular and Amchart version you are using in order to let other users know about it and also what steps have you tried in order to accomplish your need. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First step for doing this is the next:

> If you need complex information in your tooltip - tables, images, CSS
> you might consider `tooltipHTML`. It accepts any valid HTML, including full-fledged CSS, so you can do anything in there.

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

var data = [];
var value = 120;

var names = ["Raina",
  "Demarcus",
  "Carlo",
  "Jacinda",
  "Richie",
  "Antony",
  "Amada",
  "Idalia",
  "Janella",
  "Marla",
  "Curtis",
  "Shellie",
  "Meggan",
  "Nathanael",
  "Jannette",
  "Tyrell",
  "Sheena",
  "Maranda",
  "Briana",
  "Rosa",
  "Rosanne",
  "Herman",
  "Wayne",
  "Shamika",
  "Suk",
  "Clair",
  "Olivia",
  "Hans",
  "Glennie",
];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  value += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 5);
  data.push({ category: names[i], value: value });
}

chart.data = data;
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 15;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeDasharray = "1,3";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -90;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "left";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.5;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dx", function(dx, target) {
    return -target.maxRight / 2;
})

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipHTML = `<center><strong>YEAR 2020</strong></center>
<hr />
<table class="test_table">
<tr>
  <th align="left">Cars</th>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th align="left">Motorcycles</th>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th align="left">Bicycles</th>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr />`;
/*series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series.fillOpacity = 0;
series.strokeOpacity = 1;
series.strokeDashArray = "1,3";
series.columns.template.width = 0.01;*/


var bullet = series.bullets.create(am4charts.CircleBullet);

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.test_table{
  color: red;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Here's the [doc](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/tooltips-with-rich-html-content/) for further information